# How can i make an object to associate a number with a specific string

Tags: java

I have an object named skill, that is initialized with 6 int values.

I'm trying to make the object to associate that number with a specific string, so the object will internally substitute the received int by specific string.

Example of the association i want:
`1=disastous, 2=poor, 3=weak ...`

I can't remember how i can do that in java, i suppose that it's not with an enumerated. How can I do that?

Comment: perhaps you could use Enums??

Comment: use a hashmap from int to string or enum

Comment: I cannot understand how an enum can solve my problem... I wnat the object to allways pick the int and store the data as a String that i previosly specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending upon [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23954524/474189), by implementing some helper methods (namely `fromInt`) you can make your enum more usable:

```
public enum SkillLevel {    
    DISASTROUS(1, "Disastrous"),
    POOR(2, "Poor"),
    WEAK(3, "Weak");    

    private final int intValue;
    private final String description;        

    private SkillLevel(int intValue, String description) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public static SkillLevel fromInt(int value) {
        for (SkillLevel level : values()) {
            if (level.getIntValue() == value) {
                return level;
            }
        }        
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such level");
    }
}
```

So in your Skills object, if you receive an int value you can just do:

```
SkillLevel level = SkillLevel.fromInt(value);
```

You can then access the string value with:

```
level.getDescription();
```

Enums are the elegant solution to this problem and are far more powerful than maps. You can add more fields and data to an enum if your requirements increase, whereas a map can only ever link one value to another value.

Comment: tks for the help. i go for the more elegant solution. =)

Answer (score 3):

If the associations are static and known, use an enum.

```
    public enum Items {
        disastous(1),
        poor(2),
        weak(3);

        int id;
        Items(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes the associations are only 10, static and known. But how can i in my skills object receive the int value and make it store the string value?

Comment: @UcanDoIt I would store the string separately from the enum name, as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5698206/474189). Note: this comment isn't a reply to your comment, but rather an observation about the answer.

Comment: Seems more easy with an HashMap. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @UcanDoIt Why use a hash-map when enums were *designed* for this sort of purpose?

Comment: @UcanDoIt The Type-Safe Enume Pattern was not designed for this purpose. It was designed for the opposite purpose, enumerating strings, in a way that is type safe. So if you had a method that only had a handful of sensible inputs, like days of the week, or planets in the solar system, you couldn't feed it parameters it couldn't understand.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I suspect this skill level will be used elsewhere in the application, after parsing, so using an enum has many benefits.

Comment: @Duncan Many benefits? Like?

Answer (score 1):

An associtive array ?

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map  = new HashMap<>();
```

put you associations into the map as pairs and the simply return map.get(value)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'm doing it in my current project. Providing all Stats need the same Human Readable value for a given number. Works like a charm.

```
public abstract class AbstractStat implements IStat
{
    private static final Map<Integer, String> hrNames;

    static
    {
        hrNames = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        hrNames.put(1, "None");
        hrNames.put(2, "Poor");
        hrNames.put(3, "Below Average");
        hrNames.put(4, "Average");
        hrNames.put(5, "Above Average");
        hrNames.put(6, "Good");
    }
}
```

Comment: An enum would be a much more elegant solution :-(

Comment: Well, provide a counter argument. Why is a map superior? My answer already explains why I believe an enum is the right choice.

Comment: Yes. But your explaination is wrong. Suggesting that a type safe enum solves a problem that the type-safe enum does not solve, is incorrect. What solves this problem is an associative array (the hint is in the name). But I'm not here to argue. If you use Enums for things that they are not designed to do, that's your headache, not mine.

Comment: I'm working on the assumption that this value is used elsewhere in the application. I suppose if that assumption is wrong, the use of an enum loses many of its benefits. Although I would still err on the side of an enum just in case the application is refactored later. I'm struggling to understand what you think is wrong about an enum - can you elaborate?

Comment: A Type-Safe Enum operates on strings. It solved the problem of having a string-like parameter, that can be handled in a a uniform, type-safe way. Because in Java, you can add methods to an enum (because it's a POJO) to coerce it into what you want still doesn't mean you should. But yes we're clearly operating on different assumptions. My assumption is that they are int's for a reason, most likely because you want to use them fir arithmetic, otherwise OP could just use strings.