# Rank ArrayList<String> with int in java

Tags: java, string, integer

I want to rank in java an `ArrayList<String>` with the number of times that the String appears.
Like this: if I have an

`ArrayList<String>= [French, English, German, French, French, Belgium, English, Belgium]`

I count the number that `"French", "English", "Belgium",etc.` appear. So French appear 3 times, English 2 times, Belgium 2 times, German one times. Then I want to rank the `ArrayList<String>` in function of the number.

The result will be:

```
French 3
English 2 
Belgium 2
German 1
```

How I can do this? How to associate an integer and a String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking to associate strings to ints in a cleaner/more efficient way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698150/looking-to-associate-strings-to-ints-in-a-cleaner-more-efficient-way)

Comment: Parse the arrayList and create a map with "language" as key and "count" as value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you need to associate data, you should be thinking `Map` all the way.  `HashMap` is the basic class used for this.  So you can iterate over your list and create your associations in a `Map<String, Integer>`.

```
List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
// ...populate it

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    
for(String string : stuff) {
    if(map.containsKey(string)) {
        map.put(string, map.get(string) + 1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(string, 1);
    }
}
```

Check out the full [HashMap API here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. But how to rank the map?

Comment: @user3590882 Glad it helped you. :)  As far as ordering the `HashMap`, you really don't, usually.  A `HashMap` is fundamentally unordered.  If you want to sort based on the key, you can use a `TreeMap`, but if you want to sort of the value, as I suspect, it becomes a bit harder, especially since there can be identical values (whereas the key is unique).  You can check out [this Q&A for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119401/1435657).

Comment: I did this 
    map=new TreeMap<String,Integer>(map);
And I have the map sorted by String, but how to sort it by key value?
I tried 
    map=new TreeMap<String,Integer>(map.values);
but it's not recognized...

PS: How to write a text like a code in this forum?

Answer (score 6):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use the `frequency` method of the `Collections` class:

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)
```

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to
>   the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e
>   in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).

If you need to *count* the occurrences for all elements, use a Map and loop cleverly :)
Or put your list in a Set and loop on each element of the set with the `frequency` method above. HTH

**EDIT / Java 8**: If you fancy a more functional, Java 8 one-liner solution with lambdas, try:

```
Map<String, Long> occurrences = 
  list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
```

And then sort the map by value.

Comment: I wouldn't upvote for the `frequency` comment, since it still requires that the coder iterate over the `List` and store/associate the values somehow.  But +1 for sick Java 8 skills. :)

Comment: I don't understand your answer...
When I try     .stream() on my list this method doesn't exist...

Comment: @momo70 Upgrade to Java 8 and enjoy functional interfaces! is there anything else that you don't understand?

Comment: I found a solution [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/12/how-to-sort-hashmap-java-by-key-and-value.html)

But @okiharaherbst what is `w -> w`?

Comment: @momo70,`w -> w` is called a _lambda expression_, and has been introduced to Java in its 8th release to bring some _functional programming_ constructs to the language. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html and http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html if you're interested and need a primer on the topic. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a Language class:

```
public class Language {
  private String name;
  private int count;

  public Language(String name) { this.name = name; this.count = 0; }
  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public int getCount() { return this.count; }
  public void setCount(int count) { this.count = count; }
}
```

And then, create a list of languages from the ArrayList:

```
List<String> languageNames = // your language names
Map<String, Language> map = new HashMap<String, Language>();

for (String languageName : languageNames) {
  Language language = map.get(languageName);
  if (language == null) {
    language = new Language(languageName);
  } else {
    language.setCount(language.getCount() + 1);
  }
  map.put(languageName, language);
}

List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>(map.values());
```

After that, we sort, and print the languages:

```
Collections<Language>.sort(languages, new Comparator<Language>() {
  public int compare(Language l1, Language l2) {
    return l1.getCount() - l2.getCount();
  }
});

System.out.println(languages);
```

Comment: How to use this on the code of Jeff Gohlke?
Because his code works on my ArrayList and your code is not the same that I need, so I have to adapt your code to mine. But how? Should I take only the third part about Collection?

Comment: OP wants to _Rank a List<String> with int in Java_ which roughly translates into using a map. Don't you think that dedicating a whole class to this is a little too stiff?

Comment: We can avoid using classes. But, we need to somehow bind language name with its frequency (number of appearance). The Language class is used for this purpose.